# Creating a weighted, directed graph from ordered triples

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a relatively large set of data that I am trying to turn into a weighted, directed graph. The data concerns the inflow of migrants based on country of origin. I currently have three columns of data in excel: a number representing country migrated to ($a_i$), a number representing country of origin ($b_i$), and the number of migrants, $n$, who have traveled from $b_i$ to $a_i$.

If I turn this data into a set of ordered triples ($b_i$,$a_i$,$\sigma$) where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are as defined above, and $\sigma$ represents some sort of weight (which I will calculate based upon $n$), would it be possible to have mathematica interpret these triples as directions for constructing a graph? That is, could I somehow yield a directed graph such that each triple corresponds to an edge $b_i\rightarrow a_i$ with weight $\sigma$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sure; look up `DirectedEdge[]` and the `EdgeWeight` option of `Graph[]`. If you want a demo of how you can use these; please include a (small) example.

Comment: Half the work is importing the data. You merely need to import the Excel file as a list through something like `dataFile = Import["T10.xls"]`  I suggest working first with a small number of records till you get a feel for how the data are organized.

Comment: Does inflow exist between every possible pair of countries? In other words do you have a complete weighted graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume the following:

1. If inflow is zero between some countries - there is no edge between them
2. Inflow can be non-zero even between non-bordering countries

I will try to simulate your data - to get something that reminiscent of numbers after the import from Excel. Consider South America:

```
countries = CountryData["SouthAmerica"]; countries // Length
```

> 14

This will simulate your data

```
directions = Union@Table[{countries[[Mod[k, 14] + 1]], 
     RandomChoice[DeleteCases[countries, countries[[Mod[k, 14] + 1]]]]}, {k, 1, 20}];

flows = DirectedEdge @@@ directions;

data = Transpose[Append[Transpose[#], RandomReal[1, Length[#]]] &@directions];

Grid[data, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

An obvious thing to do is to plot this graph in a **geographical** layout of the countries. The lighter the color of the edge, the greater is the inflow. I also color countries according to population:

```
Show[
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[GrayLevel[.6]], Opacity[.5], 
     ColorData["TemperatureMap"][
      CountryData[#, "Population"]/1.95423`*^8], 
     CountryData[#, "Polygon"]} & /@ CountryData["SouthAmerica"]],
 Graph[
  countries,
  flows,
  EdgeWeight -> data[[All, 3]],
  EdgeStyle -> 
   MapThread[
    Rule, {flows, 
     Directive[ColorData["SolarColors"][#], Thickness[.01]] & /@ 
      data[[All, 3]]}],
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  VertexCoordinates -> (Reverse[
       CountryData[#, "CenterCoordinates"]] & /@ 
     CountryData["SouthAmerica"]),
  EdgeShapeFunction -> 
   GraphElementData[{"FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .035}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

You may also try other layouts - coming from graph properties:

```
Graph[
   countries,
   flows,
   EdgeWeight -> data[[All, 3]],
   EdgeStyle -> 
    MapThread[
     Rule, {flows, 
      Directive[ColorData["SolarColors"][#], Thickness[.01]] & /@ 
       data[[All, 3]]}],
   VertexLabels -> "Name",
   EdgeShapeFunction -> 
    GraphElementData[{"FilledArrow", "ArrowSize" -> .035}],
   GraphLayout -> #,
   ImagePadding -> 40] & /@ 
     {"CircularEmbedding", "SpringElectricalEmbedding"}//Row
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful answer, thanks so much.